# How to use opencv flann::Index?

Tags: c++, opencv, knn

I have some problems with opencv flann::Index -

I'm creating index

```
    Mat samples = Mat::zeros(vfv_net_quie.size(),24,CV_32F);
        for (int i =0; i < vfv_net_quie.size();i++)
        {
           for (int j = 0;j<24;j++)
           {
              samples.at<float>(i,j)=(float)vfv_net_quie[i].vfv[j];
           }
        }
    cv::flann::Index flann_index(
            samples,
            cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams(4),
            cvflann::FLANN_DIST_EUCLIDEAN
               );
    flann_index.save("c:\\index.fln");
```

A fter that I'm tryin to load it and find nearest neiborhoods

```
cv::flann::Index flann_index(Mat(),
    cv::flann::SavedIndexParams("c:\\index.fln"),
    cvflann::FLANN_DIST_EUCLIDEAN
    );

cv::Mat resps(vfv_reg_quie.size(), K, CV_32F);
cv::Mat nresps(vfv_reg_quie.size(), K, CV_32S);
cv::Mat dists(vfv_reg_quie.size(), K, CV_32F);

flann_index.knnSearch(sample,nresps,dists,K,cv::flann::SearchParams(64));
```

And have access violation in miniflann.cpp in line

```
((IndexType*)index)->knnSearch(_query, _indices, _dists, knn,
                          (const ::cvflann::SearchParams&)get_params(params));
```

Please help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not load the flann-file into a `Mat()`, as it is the place where the index is stored. It is a temporary object destroyed after the constructor was called. That's why the index isn't pointing anywhere useful when you call `knnSearch()`.

I tried following:

```
cv::Mat indexMat;
cv::flann::Index flann_index(
    indexMat,
    cv::flann::SavedIndexParams("c:\\index.fln"),
    cvflann::FLANN_DIST_EUCLIDEAN
);
```

resulting in:

```
Reading FLANN index error: the saved data size (100, 64) or type (5) is different from the passed one (0, 0), 0
```

which means, that the matrix has to be initialized with the correct dimensions (seems very stupid to me, as I don't necessarily know, how many elements are stored in my index).

```
cv::Mat indexMat(samples.size(), CV_32FC1);
cv::flann::Index flann_index(
    indexMat,
    cv::flann::SavedIndexParams("c:\\index.fln"),
    cvflann::FLANN_DIST_EUCLIDEAN
);
```

does the trick.

Comment: A point to note is that you need to provide the actual original dataset, not just a Mat with the right dimensions. It's not very clear in the OpenCV documentation, but is mentioned in Section 3.3.4 of the [flann documentation](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.6.pdf)

Comment: @Sau isn't Section 3.3.4 talking about Matlab and not C++? Have you verified your comment in OpenCV or in the C++ version of flann?

Answer (score 2):

In the accepted answer is somehow not clear and misleading why the input matrix in the `cv::flann::Index` constructor must have the same dimension as the matrix used for generating the saved Index. I'll elaborate on @Sau's comment with an example.

`KDTreeIndex` was generated using as input a `cv::Mat sample`, and then saved. When you load it, you must provide the same `sample` matrix to generate it, something like (using the templated `GenericIndex` interface):

```
cv::Mat sample(sample_num, sample_size, ... /* other params */);
cv::flann::SavedIndexParams index_params("c:\\index.fln");
cv::flann::GenericIndex<cvflann::L2<float>> flann_index(sample, index_params);
```

`L2` is the usual Euclidean distance (other types can be found in `opencv2/flann/dist.h`).

Now the index can be used as shown the find the `K` nearest neighbours of a `query` point:

```
std::vector<float> query(sample_size);
std::vector<int> indices(K);
std::vector<float> distances(K);

flann_index.knnSearch(query, indices, distances, K, cv::flann::SearchParams(64));
```

The matrix `indices` will contain the **locations** of the **nearest neighbours** **in the matrix `sample`**, which was used at first to generate the index. That's why you need to load the saved index with the very matrix used to generate the index, otherwise the returned vector will contain indices pointing to meaningless "nearest neighbours".

In addition you get a `distances` matrix containing how far are the found neighbours from your `query` point, which you can later use to perform some [inverse distance weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting), for example.

Please also note that `sample_size` has to match across `sample` matrix and `query` point.